# Undefined function 'exp' for input arguments of type 'optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression'

Tags: matlab, non-linear-regression

I was trying to write a code for non linear regression. I have a model, but when it comes to the model line i get the error Undefined function 'exp' for input arguments of type 'optim.problemdef.OptimizationExpression'. which makes no sense, exp is there in matlab functions.

Any clue what may be the problem.

````
while sol.R2 >= 1 || sol.C >= 1 % While loop repeats the program until C and R2 are acceptable
    % Loop to repeat 2 times. First time R1 and L are determined. 
    % In the second loop, R2 and C are determined. 
    % This is done for better fitting.
    for k = 1:2
        V = voltage_battery * number_of_batteries; % Series voltage
        X = A(:, 1); % Extracted time data from .dat file
        start = find(X < 0); % Looks for indexes of time=0
        stop = find(X > stop_tf * 1E-4); % Sets stopping time for curve fitting
        M = max(start); % Finds index of time=0
        N = min(stop); % Finds index of stopping time
        X = A(M:N, 1); % Trims timedata to range required
        Y = A(M:N, 2); % Trims timedata to range required
%         Y = table2array(Y); % Convert Y from table to array
        ymax = max(Y, [], 'all'); % Finds max amplitude for ylim for plot.
        
        if k == 1
            R1 = optimvar('R1'); 
            L = optimvar('L');
        elseif k == 2
            R1 = sol.R1; 
            L = sol.L;
        end
        R2 = optimvar('R2');
        C = optimvar('C');
        
        
        fun = @(R1, R2, L, C) V./(R1 + R2) - (V.*exp(-(X.*(L + C.*R1.*R2))./(2.*C.*L.*R2)).*(cosh((X.*((C.^2.*R1.^2.*R2.^2)./4 - (C.*L.*R1.*R2)./2 - C.*L.*R2.^2 + L.^2./4).^(1./2))./(C.*L.*R2)) - (C.*L.*R2.*sinh((X.*((C.^2.*R1.^2.*R2.^2)./4 - (C.*L.*R1.*R2)./2 - C.*L.*R2.^2 + L.^2./4).^(1./2))./(C.*L.*R2)).*((L + C.*R1.*R2)./(2.*C.*L.*R2) - (- C.*V.*R2.^2 + L.*V)./(C.*L.*R2.*V)))./((C.^2.*R1.^2.*R2.^2)./4 - (C.*L.*R1.*R2)./2 - C.*L.*R2.^2 + L.^2./4).^(1./2)))./(R1 + R2);

obj = sum((fun(R1, R2, L, C) - Y).^2);  ```
````